# Python creating a folder and moving a zip file inside that folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

so im wondering. I have this folder with lots of zip files. In this folder i would like to create new Folders using the names of the zip files and then move each zip file into there respective folders. would something like this be possible?

Comment: Totally possible, I'd suggest using Pathlib and the zip module from the standard lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need import `os` (list the zip files and create folders) and `shutil` (move them to corresponding folders)

```
import os
import shutil
# os.chdir("<path-to-your-folder>")
for zf in [zf for zf in os.listdir() if zf.endswith(".zip")]:
    subfolder = zf[:-4]
    os.mkdir(subfolder)
    shutil.move(src=zf,dst=subfolder)
```